# Multi level combox box?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make multi-level combobox. Here I have use following html code:

```
<select name="comboName" class="droplist droplist-by-select">
            <optgroup label="1">
                <optgroup label="1.1">
                    <option value="1.1.1"> 1.1.1 </option>
                    <option value="1.1.2"> 1.1.2 </option>
                    <option value="1.1.3"> 1.1.3 </option>
                </optgroup>
                <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="2">
                <option value="2.1">2.1</option>
                <option value="2.2" selected="selected">2.2</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

It display all the option in combobox. The problem is that how can I make option group selectable e.g. optgroup of 1.1. And the optgroup 1.1 is not indent to right under the 1 option in above example. Here, I am trying to use this for selecting category which are in different level of index.  Is there any jquery plugins for this.

Answer (score 2):

Drop down list doesn't really fit into your needs.

You better use something like `<ul>` that can be easily tweaked with jQuery.

Raw example:

```
<ul name="comboName" class="droplist droplist-by-select">
    <li><span>1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>1.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>1.1.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>1.1.2</span></li>
                    <li><span>1.1.3</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>1.2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>1.2.1</span></li>
                    <li><span>1.2.2</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
li { margin-left: 10px; cursor: pointer; }
.selected { background-color: highlight; }
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".droplist li span").hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "highlight");
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
             $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        }
    }).on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents("ul").find("li").removeClass("selected").find("span").css("background-color", "white");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        $(this).css("background-color", "highlight");
    });​
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/HUpGx/).

It still need some tweaking, but that's one possible direction to achieve what you want.

Comment: nice demo, but I'd use "backgroundcolor: transparent" instead of "backgroundcolor: wihte".

Comment: ohhh yes sure^^. was too fascinated with the demo ;)